# jQuery alternative for replacing html without breaking Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

At a certain point of my code, I need to pick up an html string coming from an AJAX request and replace a certain container with it.

I have this but, as stated in several references across the web, it is garbage collected and unbinds the event listeners

```
this.rightPanel.innerHTML = content;
```

This however, doesn't happen with jQuery `.html()` function, which keeps the event listeners working, so doing

```
$(this.rightPanel).html(content);
```

works without flaw.

I didn't want to use jQuery for DOM manipulation, even so when browsers support it natively. What's the best alternative I have to reproduce the same behavior as jQuery `.html()`?

Thank you

Comment: *"This however, doesn't happen with jQuery .html() function..."* Yes, it does. *"...which keeps the event listeners working..."* No, it doesn't.

Comment: *I didn't want to use jQuery for DOM manipulation, even so when browsers support it natively.* JQuery is JavaScript. All browsers support it nativley.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, what I meant was, I wanted to use native DOM functions, like querySelector, instead of using a library like jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This however, doesn't happen with jQuery .html() function...

Yes, it does.

> ...which keeps the event listeners working...

No, it doesn't. :-)

Like-for-like, they do the same thing to the event listeners:

```js
// DOM
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Button 1");
});

// jQuery
$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
  console.log("Button 2");
});

// Replace 'em
$("#btnRep").on("click", function() {
  var wrap1 = document.getElementById("wrap1");
  wrap1.innerHTML = wrap1.innerHTML + " (replaced)";
  var wrap2 = $("#wrap2");
  wrap2.html(wrap2.html() + " (replaced)");
});
```

```html
<p>Click Button 1, then Button 2, Then Replace, then Buttons 1 and 2 again -- you'll see *neither* of them has a handler anymore after being replaced.</p>
<div id="wrap1">
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button 1">
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
  <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Button 2">
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnRep" value="Replace">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What you've probably seen is that jQuery makes *event delegation* really, really easy: That's where you actually hook the event on an ancestor element (perhaps even `body`), but you ask jQuery to only trigger your handler if it passed through an element during bubbling. That way, you can replace the descendant elements, because the event listener isn't on them, it's on the container/ancestor.

You can do that without jQuery as well, it's just a bit more work:

```js
function addDelegated(element, eventName, selector, handler) {
  element.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
    // Start with the target element, and go through its parents
    // until we reach the element we hooked the event on (`this`)
    var element = e.target;
    while (element && element !== this) {
        // `matches` test the element against a CSS selector
        if (element.matches(selector)) {
          // Yes, trigger the handler
          return handler.call(element, e);
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
  });
}

// Hook the event on wrap1
addDelegated(document.getElementById("wrap1"), "click", "#btn1", function() {
  console.log("Button 1");
});

// Replace
document.getElementById("btnRep").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var wrap1 = document.getElementById("wrap1");
  wrap1.innerHTML = wrap1.innerHTML + " (replaced)";
});
```

```html
<p>Click Button 1, then Replace, then Button 1 again.</p>
<div id="wrap1">
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button 1">
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnRep" value="Replace">
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you mean is that jQuery implements the event listeners on a higher hierarchy element, like body, and delegates the event to the specified selector, probably when the `event.target` matches it? Thus the function you provided is similar to the `.on()` function in jQuery correct? Thank you!

Comment: @JoãoDias: jQuery **can** do that, if you ask it to; it doesn't unless you do. For instance, this binds the handler directly to the element: `$("#element").on("click", handler);` But this binds the handler to `document`, while only firing the handler if the event passed through the `#element` element: `$(document).on("click", "#element", handler);` Yes, `addDelegated` above is a sketch of how you'd do the same thing using the DOM directly instead of using the DOM via jQuery's helper functions.

Comment: that's what I was thinking. But, as many where, so have I been shielded from fully understanding what was really behind it, by using jQuery and rarely stepping out into hardcore javascript. Thank you for making that clear ;)